# Create flexbox container one after another horizontally

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am trying to create 2 flexbox containers one after the other, I have applied a number of classes combination to make this work. Flexbox gets created but when I scroll, the lower one goes below upper one. The output is as shown here: [Current Scenario Output](https://jsfiddle.net/cpw0y4t3/).

My requirement is those 2 horizontal bars to be fixed and one after another, irrespective of scrolling.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'personal/mystyles.css' %}">
 </head>
<body>

<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center pt-1 px-md-4 mb-3 border-bottom shadow-sm sticky-top" style="background-color: #80ccff;">
 <h5 class="my-0 mr-md-auto font-weight-normal">
    <p>Hello, User </p>
 </h5>
 <nav class="my-0 my-md-0 mr-md-3">
    <a class="p-2 text-dark" href=""><b>Home</b></a>
    <a class="p-2 text-dark" href=""><b>Account</b></a>
    <a class="p-2 text-dark" href=""><b>Logout</b></a></p>
 </nav>
 </div>
<!--This div will be used in different html file and first div will be included using 'include' keyword of django. -->
<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center pt-5 px-md-4 border-bottom shadow-sm sticky-top" style="background-color: #80ccaa;"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your second horizontal bar like this and add some css:

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center pt-5 px-md-4 border-bottom shadow-sm sticky-top" style="background-color: #80ccaa; position: fixed; width: 100%; margin-top: 50px"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked to come extent, but on resizing the browser, upper container gets hidden i.e Home, Account, Logout tabs go below the first div.

Comment: Edit of first comment: menu go below the second div.

Answer (score 0):

**Wrap 2 `divs` that you want side by side inside a `div` and make it `flex`**

```html
<body>
 <div class="d-flex">
  <div>...</div> // your first div
  <div>...</div> // your second div
 <div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks but you included two divs in one div container. My query is about 2 separate div containers one after the other